# How to setup 2 android emulators in android studio to test react native app

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

I added one more android emulator for react native 0.59 app test. I am able to launch 2 emulators. The `adb devices` command has the following output:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
```

When there is one emulator, I use on cmd terminal to do `react-native run-android` and another one to do `react-native log-android`. The backend server is running on the same PC. Here is the virtual devices in android studio:

[image]

What I would like to do is to launch 2 app representing 2 users connecting to the backend at the same time for testing. I tried to launched one app when 2 emulators are running and the loading of the app is extremely slow. It seems that the 2 app need to be launched on 2 different ports and the solutions I found online seems not working here. Also `react-native log-android` throws error when encountering 2 emulators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running the `metro-bundler` at 2 different ports. Open up one terminal in you project root and use the default command as below,

`react-native start`

This starts one server at port 8081 default.

And in another terminal run

`react-native start --port=9090`

This starts another server at port 9090

Now in a third terminal run

`react-native run-android`

This will compile and start the apps in both your running emulators at default port.

When the apps start up properly, select one emulator and open up the dev menu using `Ctrl+M`.

Click Dev Settings button at the bottom.

Click Debug server host & port for device button.

Type localhost:9090 or ip_address:9090 and click OK button

Reload the app and it will fetch the js bundle from your `react-native server` running at 9090 port

Comment: Following the steps to start 2 servers. But the server on port=9090 (emulator-5556) has error "Could not connect to development server". Tried the steps a couple of times and the problem is always on `emulator-5556`. `emulator-5554` works fine and load the app successfully. Individually `emulator-5556` was working fine.

Comment: Initially `emulator-5556` throws error of `Unable to load script. make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.` After clicking reloading, then the error of `Cound not connect to development server` shows.

Comment: Instead of `localhost:9090` try adding your IP like `[your.ip]:9090`

Answer (score 1):

`log-android` from `react-native` CLI is simply using `adb logcat` to show the Android logs.

`adb` has a `-s` parameter that lets you specify the emulator serial. First you'll need to list the currently open devices using `adb devices`. You'll get a list, for example:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Now you can specify the specific device:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

You can run it multiple times for all of the running devices that you wish to see logs for.

Comment: How to have 2 emulator running simultaneously under android studio? I tried to specify 2 ports but somehow it did not work.

Comment: How to get the console.log output? `logcat` outputs system messages but no console.log output.

Comment: `logcat` outputs everything, but you might need to fine-tune it. `<tag>[:priority]` can be used for this purpose. RN's `log-android` uses: `*:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`. The first `*:S` tells it to suppress all output on all tags and the other two tells it to show only RN related logs. You can do the same: `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`. You can also filter the log to contain specific words by piping `grep` to it: `adb logcat | grep YourFilter`

Comment: regarding running devices: you can do this from command line as well using avd: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd "DEVICE_NAME"`. Just put underscores instead of spaces on your emulator name

Comment: The logcat with filter outputs console.log.

Comment: I have no problem starting 2 emulators. But how to start app on 2 emulator representing 2 different users connecting to the backend?

Comment: that really depends on your app's setup. there's no issue running the same app on different devices which use the same bundler process. i'm not sure what you mean regarding 2 different users, each emulator can perform its own "login" if required. If you're doing e2e tests and you have some sort of mock server, then controlling different ports must be in your testing infrastructure (for example: identify that an instance of the server is already running and open a new instance on a different port)

Comment: Many thanks for the `adb logcat` command and it works. i wish I can send you a portion of the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

@NishantNiar solution is correct but I want to change here something
First I run my both different emulator.
Then I run `yarn start --port=9090` instead of `npm start --port=9090` because it gave me an error.
And then in another terminal I run `npm run android`, then automatically the first emulator started on `8081 port` which is default port, and another emulator started on `9090 port`.
Hope this will help you.